# Não tenho mais acesso às filas de análise. Por quê?

Tags: suporte

Após algum tempo no SO hoje, atingi o limite diário de votos. Até aí, tudo bem. Porém, após isso, quando eu tento acessar as filas de análise, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

[image: "nenhuma fila de análise disponível para você"]

É um bug, ou para realizar análises é necessário ter votos disponíveis no Stack Overflow?

Comment: Como estão sendo os resultados de suas auditorias de análise? Se errar muitas auditorias o sistema lhe bloqueia.

Comment: Dúvida: está tentando abrir as filas de análise do site ou do Meta? São filas distintas e como são reputações distintas, pode ser que do Meta você ainda não tem acesso.

Comment: @AugustoVasques tenho um registro positivo de 65 sinalizações úteis e 9 rejeitadas (quase todas as rejeitadas são de antes de eu compreender como funcionavam as sinalizações padrões)

Comment: @Woss as do site. Até antes de atingir a quantidade máxima de votos eu conseguia, depois só apareceu aquela mensagem e parei de ter acesso

Comment: @Woss a reputação do principal é usada para o meta, mas no meta costuma ter bem pouca fila, e eu acho que o AP pode estar aqui ou no principal sem ter nada para analisar mesmo, ele já analisou tudo o que tinha, só isso, porque bloqueio ele não tem.

Comment: Eu **acho** que quando você atinge o cap de votos diário, as filas que esperam que você vote nas postagens são desativadas (inclusive a de fechamento, para o sistema é tudo voto).

Comment: @bfavaretto provavelmente era, assim que "virou" o dia ganhei o acesso de novo